# Bash: Iteration through directories acts weird

Tags: linux, bash, unix, iteration, filesize

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "/home/$USER/sessions/out/*/"; do
    size=$(stat -c %s $dir/log)
    if [ 1 -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $size.
    fi
done
```

Started using bash today. I am trying to check the size of log file in all directories in home/sessions/out. If 1!=0 (always, as test), the file size of log should be printed. What I am getting is:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 57344001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 966904.
```

I expect a period after each file size, I actually get one period. Are all file sizes appended to variable size before it reaches the if clause? I am confused.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the /home/$USER/sessions/out/*/

Comment: Perfect. :) I'll mark your answer as correct when you move your comment to an answer.

Comment: In [the] future, please don't include statements such as `if [ 1 -ne 0 ]; then ...`, because all they do is create confusion (despite your explanation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that pathname expansion (expansion of '*') happens in the `stat` invocation, not in the loop declaration, because the path in the loop is quoted, but the path in `stat` invocation is not.

I.e. only one iteration of the loop is happening, with `dir` having value of `/home/$USER/sessions/out/*/`. That is then being expanded in stat invocation, supplying all the paths matching `/home/$USER/sessions/out/*/log` to `stat`.

The solution is to unquote the path in the loop declaration and quote it in the `stat` invocation.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /home/$USER/sessions/out/*/; do
    size=$(stat -c %s "$dir/log")
    if [ 1 -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $size.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Although unnecessary in this case, in general you can quote the portions of the pattern that might need to be quoted (such as the parameter expansions): `for dir in "/home/$USER/sessions/out/"*/; do`.

Comment: You should use `echo "$size"` with double quotes also, if merely to demonstrate that quoting variable interpolations should be the norm.

Comment: @triplee I agree that always quoting is good. However, I left out quoting here as not strictly necessary and to keep changes from the original more clear to illustrate the point better.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole program can be simplified down to just one line

```
stat -c %s /home/$USER/sessions/out/*/log
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you have a test condition of 1 != 0, which always evaluates to true in there. But, the following loop will do it for you:

```
for LOGFILE in `find $LOGPATH -type f -iname 'log'`
do
   echo `stat -c %s $LOGFILE`'.'
done
```

I used the variable LOGPATH where you would use '/home/$USER/sessions/out.' If this is in a script file, it would be wise to use a variable like that, at the top of the script, so that it could easily be changed later if need be.

The '-type f' is there in case there are directories with the name log, that you might not want to parse. If that is not the case, then you can omit that.

I used the find command, because you have much more finely grained control over it. You can set search depth, file type, file size, and so on. To get the period at the end, simply single quote a period right at the end of the echo statement.

If you needed the filename, and then the size, just change the echo statement, like so:

```
echo "$LOGFILE" `stat -c %s $LOGFILE`'.'
```

Comment: Your `find` command will find `log` files _anywhere_ in the target directory's subtree, not just in immediate subfolders, as in the OP's code. Parsing `find` output with `for` is never a good idea, as it breaks with paths containing spaces, for instance.

Comment: You're absolutely right @mklement0. But, if the variable name is double quoted, that is accounted for. I will edit my answer to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is NO safe way to parse output from a command substitution (`\`...\`` or - preferably - `$(...)`) in a `for` loop. Double-quoting the variable inside the command substitution may make the command itself more robust, but the `for` loop will still have problems with output lines containing, e.g., embedded spaces, or looking like a glob (e.g., `*`). Double-quoting the command substitution as a whole won't work either, as that will assign the *entire* output to the `for` variable _at once_; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for background information.